# Showing Different aggregate for different products

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I want a code which is used to generate aggregate product by product. The product aggregate can be any like from Year to Date(YTD), Months to Date(MTD) and Quarter to Date(QTD). The user will pass the parameter on that basis the code should decide what kind of output the user wants.

```
If the Year is passing in the parameter than the code should generate the aggregate from the starting of the year to the sysdate.

If the Quarter No is passing in the parameter than the code should generate the aggregate from the starting of the quarter to the sysdate.

If the Month is passing in the parameter than the code should generate the aggregate from the starting of the month to the sysdate.
```

It means that on the basis of the parameter it should be able to decide which kind of user want from those 3. My input data is like this-

```
Product Table

    Product_ID       Product_name          Price
    1                  Mobile               200
    2                   T.V.                400
    3                  Mixer                300
```

and

Sales Table-

```
 Product_ID          Sales_Date         Quantity
    1                   01-01-2015            30
    2                   03-01-2015            40
    3                   06-02-2015            10
    1                   22-03-2015            30
    2                   09-04-2015            10
    3                   21-05-2015            40
    1                   04-06-2015            40
    2                   29-07-2015            30
    1                   31-08-2015            30
    3                   14-09-2015            30
```

And my ouput column contains 3 columns that are- Product_id, Product_Name and Total. The column Total_Amount(quantity*price) have to calculate sale on the basis of input given by user and is be something like this-
For example ,

```
 If pro_test is the procedure then 
call pro_test('YTD') -- Should Return the ProductWise YTD,
call pro_test('QTD') -- Should Return the ProductWise QTD and so on..
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `WHERE` clause :-) List your conditions with `OR` and you are done.

```
select 
  p.product_id, 
  p.product_name, 
  coalesce(sum(s.quantity * p.price), 0) as total
from product p 
left join sales s on s.product_id = p.product_id
where 
  (:aggregate = 'YTD' and to_char(s.sales_date, 'yyyy') = to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy'))
or
  (:aggregate = 'MTD' and to_char(s.sales_date, 'yyyymm') = to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymm'))
or
  (:aggregate = 'QTD' and to_char(s.sales_date, 'yyyyq') = to_char(sysdate, 'yyyyq'))
group by p.product_id, p.product_name;
```

EDIT: Here is how the corresponding PL/SQL function would look like:

```
create or replace function matches_date_aggregate(in_sales_date date, in_aggregate char) 
  return integer as
begin
  if (in_aggregate = 'YTD' and to_char(in_sales_date, 'yyyy') = to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy'))
  or (in_aggregate = 'MTD' and to_char(in_sales_date, 'yyyymm') = to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymm'))
  or (in_aggregate = 'QTD' and to_char(in_sales_date, 'yyyyq') = to_char(sysdate, 'yyyyq')) then
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
  end if;
end matches_date_aggregate;
```

Your query's `WHERE` clause would become:

```
where matches_date_aggregate(s.sales_date, :aggregate) = 1
```

The function cannot return `BOOLEAN` unfortunately, for even though Oracle's PL/SQL knows the `BOOLEAN` data type, Oracle SQL doesn't.

Comment: but if there is more than one year than it would work? BTW you forgot to include group by in the end :P .

Comment: You want all records from beginning of this year / of this month / of this quarter till now. So there is always only one year involved. And yes, I forgot the `GROUP BY` clause. I'll edit :-)

Comment: Actually I have solved that part..what I want is if the query can be framed dynamically and can it take parameters rather than this.

Comment: It does take a parameter: `:aggregate`. Depending on its value you will either aggregate the year, the quarter or the month.

Comment: Your procedure is compiling without any error but on executing its giving error- wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MATCHES_DATE_AGGREGATE'

Comment: Strange, it works in my system (Oracle 11.2). What tool do you use to execute the query? Maybe it helps to change `in_aggregate char` to `in_aggregate varchar2`? It should work with `char` nonetheless, because in_aggregate is a string and :aggregate should be a string, too, of course.

Comment: can you show me the line from which you are executing as I have the same (Oracle 11.2)..I don't know what is the problem because now its giving error-'MATCHES_DATE_AGGREGATE' is not a procedure or is undefined

Comment: I am using TOAD. I execute the CREATE OR REPLACE thing, and the function gets created. I then execute `select matches_date_aggregate(sysdate - 40, :aggregate) from dual`, a popup asks me for the value, I enter YTD or something and then I get 0 or 1.

Comment: Well, I thought that's what it's all about; you say which aggregation you want (YTD or MTD or QTD) and the query collects the data for you. This is why you put that function call in your WHERE clause. If that is not what you want, then maybe you should update your question and show us the desired results.

Comment: If you want the query executed within a function, then you'd need to write a pipelined table function and query it thus: `select * from table ( myqueryfunction(:aggregate) ); `. Look up "Oracle pipelined table function" somewhere on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks man! I nearly get what I want.. one last request...can it can be made in a procedure and than passing the parameter like 'YTD' or 'QTD' and by this it will do aggregate.

Comment: The function I have shown you only checks if date and aggregate match, but this is actually all that's needed. As mentioned, if you want the whole query in a function instead, then you'd have to write a pipelined table function. And you'd still need a query to read from that function, only it would be a very simple query then, as shown..

Comment: yeah...not worry about pipelined functions..can you just make it through procedure and pass parameter like 'YTD' or 'MTD' or 'QTD'

Comment: I don't understand. The function shown accepts such a parameter. It also needs the date of course because the function must know the \*TD parameter plus a date to be able to evaluate. So *either* you have a function that just does the evaluation and accepts \*TD plus date *or* you write a pipelined function and only pass \*TD, because it gets the date from the records then.

Comment: So what changes must be done to make it pipelined...I have looked at it but I don't have that much knowledge about functions and all..

Comment: Then why don't you go without one for now? And learn it step by step. There should be manuals online on how to create such function. If you don't find anything useful on Google or here, then ask this as a new question. But first do some research on your own and try.